# Copy Values down a row on time triggered script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am struggling to find a way to get this script to automatically go down one row after it has been executed. I tried using getlastrow, with little success.
I feel like I'm missing something really basic here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = source.getRange("E2");

  range.copyValuesToRange(226810801, 6, 6,4,4);

}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? eaxctly? Append E2's value to the bottom?

Comment: I'm trying to get the current value of my portfolio at a certain time, then copy it over to a column where it feeds to a graph. So I need it to copy --> copy to cell, copy--> copy to cell + down 1 row. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this at the end of your function:

```
var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
var rg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1).activate();
```

Comment: It does for me.  I use it in an onOpen to go to the bottom of a spreadsheet.

Comment: It brings back the error that 'getLastRow" is undefined.

Comment: Okay I changed it to getSheets()[0].

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
    sh.getRange("A1").setValue("");
//getLastRow returns undefined if the sheet is blank.
    var rg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1).activate();
```